# Using PHP to play sound

Tags: php, file, audio, random, playback

my php code to fetch all sound files, random way, in a folder is this:

```
$files = glob("audio/*.mp3");
$random = $files[array_rand($files)];
```

and to play them i use:

```
<audio src="<?php echo $random; ?>" width="400" height="200" controls></audio>
```

What i want is to play the sound files pressing a HTML button tag and not seeing the default HTML5 audio player. Just like Spotify or similar.

I tried making it with button onclick="function()" but with javascript wich is a client language i don't know a way to loop all files in my folder, just like i did with the php code above.

Any ideas? Many thanks...

Comment: You use php for the file system part and javascript for the client side part. So either you prepare different "players", or you call a php script from the `src` property of the auto element.

Comment: where do you want to play the sound? on the server or on the client?

Comment: OK. So how could i access the PHP array inside javascript function so that i can make: <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-play white" onclick="playsound()" type="button"></button>

Comment: I want to play the sound files located on a folder called audio inside my web page root.

Comment: With this line of code i partially solved the problem, but i need the icon to press and play the file to be another one other than the browser's doom default one. -> <a onclick="this.firstChild.play()"><audio src="<?php echo $random; ?>"></audio>▸</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few minutes after asking i solved the question by myself. Been dealing with this four a couple of hours, so here it is:

```
<a onclick="this.firstChild.play()"><audio src="<?php echo $random; ?>"></audio>&#9658;</a>
```

Used the browser DOM and a html special caracter & #9658;. It does the trick, in spite of not allowing the use of an icon image.

**Thanks to all :)**